# Excel VBA - select a dynamic cell range

Tags: excel, range, vba

I want to be able to dynamically select a range of cells (the heading row), where the row is 1 but the columns with be for 1 to last column, where "A" is the first Column and where "M" is the last column. I know how to find the last column, but I don't know how to modified the below range to input the first and last column as "A" and "M".

```
 Range("A1:M1").Select
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to select a variable range containing all headers cells:

```
Dim sht as WorkSheet
Set sht = This Workbook.Sheets("Data")

'Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select '<<< NOT ROBUST

sht.Range(sht.Cells(1,1),sht.Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

...as long as there's no other content on that row.

EDIT: updated to stress that when using `Range(Cells(...), Cells(...))` it's good practice to qualify both `Range` and `Cells` with a worksheet reference.

Answer (score 12):

```
sub selectVar ()
    dim x,y as integer
    let srange = "A" & x & ":" & "m" & y
    range(srange).select
end sub
```

I think this is the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly for me in Excel 2016

Answer (score 4):

So it depends on how you want to pick the incrementer, but this should work:

```
Range("A1:" & Cells(1, i).Address).Select
```

Where `i` is the variable that represents the column you want to select (1=A, 2=B, etc.). Do you want to do this by column letter instead? We can adjust if so :)

If you want the beginning to be dynamic as well, you can try this:

```
Sub SelectCols()

    Dim Col1 As Integer
    Dim Col2 As Integer

    Col1 = 2
    Col2 = 4

    Range(Cells(1, Col1), Cells(1, Col2)).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to used this method the most, it will auto select the first column to the last column being used. However, if the last cell in the first row or the last cell in the first column are empty, this code will not calculate properly. Check the [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range) for other methods to dynamically select cell range.

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when first column has value on last row and first row has a value in the last column

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

End Sub
```