# Setting up a dynamic range in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm basing my code off of this.
[Excel VBA - select a dynamic cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064731/excel-vba-select-a-dynamic-cell-range)

I'm trying to find the syntax to create a dynamic range. Example: I always start on D8 but the  upper bound of the range is based on an int count in another cell. [h4]

```
Dim count As Integer
count = Sheet2.Cells(8,1).Value
Set refRng = Sheet2.Range("D8:" & Cells(8, i).Address)
```

Is the relevant code sample.

I now know that Sheet2.Range("H1") doesn't return an int, it returns a variant or something?

I've tried a million different things and have figured out that none of them work. There has to be a better way to set up a dynamic range.

Comment: `Cells(8, 1)` = "A8".  If you want cell H1 it would be `Cells(1, 8)` or `Cells(1, "H")`.  If you want cell H4 it would be `Cells(4, 8)` or `Cells(4, "H")`

Comment: Alternately, just `Range("H1")` or `Range("H4")`

Comment: Wowww. If you want to throw that down as an answer I'll upvote it. My stuff now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally a comment, but it is also the solution so I am adding it as an answer

`Cells(8, 1)` = "A8". If you want cell H1 it would be `Cells(1, 8)` or `Cells(1, "H")`. If you want cell H4 it would be `Cells(4, 8)` or `Cells(4, "H")`.

Alternately, just `Range("H1")` or `Range("H4")`

Answer (score 6):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but in terms of messing around with ranges maybe this is a start:

```
Option Explicit

Sub select_Range()

Dim count As Integer
count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A8").Value

Dim i As Integer
i = count

Dim refRng As Excel.Range
Set refRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D8:D" & i)

refRng.Select

End Sub
```

This results in the following on `Sheet2`:

[image]