# vba error handling selecting a dynamic cell range

Tags: excel, dynamic, error-handling, range, vba

reading through the thread [Excel VBA - select a dynamic cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064731/excel-vba-select-a-dynamic-cell-range/20820483#20820483)

I have an additional question to top up your answers, if it finds out that there is an not srange (doesnt find the dynamic range sought), how would we go about the error to make it do something else instead?

A lot to learn about error handling in my to do list!!

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not approve of the answers to the earlier question.  Yes, they provide good answers to the question, "How do I do X?", but none add that you should not do X.

I know the Macro Recorder makes heavy use of Selection but the macro is recording user actions as they occur; its does not know the user's intention and cannot create good VBA.  There is always a VBA alternative to selecting a range that is better, faster and easier to understand.  Perhaps I should say **nearly** always because there are obscure situations where selection may be the easier solution.

For example, you can if you wish select a range and they paste it somewhere else but I find the following easier to code and understand:

```
range.Copy Destination := Cell
```

OK, I will put my hobby-horse back in the cupboard and answer your question.

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = expression returning a range

' Examples from question
Set Rng = Range("A1:M1")
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
Set Rng = Range("A1:" & Cells(1, i).Address)
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, Col1), Cells(1, Col2)) 

If Rng Is Nothing Then

  ' Code to handle situations where range does not exist

Else

  ' Code to handle situations where range does exist

End If
```